# Sharing authentication across Catalyst apps

Tags: perl, catalyst

I have a three applications that I would like to keep separate for manageability purposes. They run as a Plack server as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429052/multiple-vs-single-catalyst-applications), proxied behind nginx.

I would like to have a separate application to manage logins, and have that login and its authentication process shared across all other apps, with authorization done via roles.

I would like to use Catalyst::Authentication::Store::DBIx::Class for storage.

I have tried managing authentication at the Plack level with Catalyst::Authentication::Credential::Remote doing it at the Catalyst level (which would be ideal), but can't seem to make the login seen by the Catalyst apps.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharing the store is easy -- you can either just use the DBIC session store and duplicate the config in all of the apps, or you can create a subclass of the DBIC store with a `__PACKAGE__->config` line containing the stuff that all of the apps have in common, and then specify your subclass in the session config.

As for the state -- you can use State::Cookie *if* the apps share a domain in common -- you just need to set the `cookie_domain` and/or `cookie_path` options in your session config so that the cookie gets set in a way that it will be visible to all of the apps, and set the `cookie_name` config option to the same thing in all apps, because otherwise they would all get different cookie names based on their different application class names.